# Mass Classification Attribute Removal

Tags: maximo

I was wondering if anyone else has gone though a massive classification restructure process, and knew of a way to efficiently remove attributes from a classification. Preferably via the MXLoader, or the import/export functionality built into Maximo. I know going into every individual classification that needs to have some specific attributes removed can be achieved, just hoping someone might know a better way to accomplish this.

Essentially what I am hoping to accomplish is the following with out going directly through the UI for each classification.

Pre-update

Classification A
(Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3
Attribute 4
Attribute 5)

Post update

Classification A
(Attribute 1
Attribute 2
Attribute 5)

I have tried to export the .csv file using the object structure we have built supporting classstructure, classspec, and classusewith then imported the file back post removing an unwanted attribute using the sync function, but was not successful and not 100% sure where to go from there if the feat is indeed possible via theses means.

Thanks ahead of time for any potential help/support.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a data load, you'll need to load XML, not flat / CSV. This XML file will need to be loaded via the External Systems > Enterprise Services tab, after you've built an Enterprise Service for your Object Structure and associated that Enterprise Service with an External System. Your top level tag, for a given classification, will need to have attribute action="Change" and the child tag for the attribute will need to have an attribute of action="Delete". With a little string concatenation in your spreadsheet tool, you should be able to easily upcycle your CSV into the necessary XML.